# wordpress multilingual with google api

Tags: wordpress, google-api, multilingual

I am building a website in wordpress. I wish to use google's multilingual API in it.
Is there a ready made plugin available for this? If yes please provide links.

If there is any other way please let me know. The website will be built in wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this was what you where looking for:

[Google Language Translator](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-language-translator/)